# Mockito: use InOrder with spy object

Tags: junit, mockito, spy

I want to check the invocation order of some methods using mockito. One of the methods I want to check is on a mock, the other one is in the real class that I am testing, so I am using a spy object for checking that:

However, mockito is only aware about calls on the mock methods, but not on the spy object:

```java
    MigrationServiceImpl migrationServiceSpy = spy(migrationServiceImpl);

    // I have tested without no more configuraitons on the spy, and also with the following
    // by separate (one by one)

    // I tried this:
    doNothing().when(migrationServiceSpy).updateCheckpointDate(eq(migration), any(Instant.class)); // In this case the call is not tracked by InOrder
    // And this:
    when(migrationServiceSpy.updateCheckpointDate(eq(migration), any(Instant.class))).thenReturn(true); // In this case the call is not tracked by InOrder
    // And this:
    when(migrationServiceSpy.updateCheckpointDate(eq(migration), any(Instant.class))).thenCallRealMethod(); // This line is throwing a null pointer exception but I don't understand why, since  if I do not spy the real object it works without failing.

    //Here I call the real method
    migrationServiceImpl.updateStatus(DEFAULT_MIGRATION_ID, inProgressStatus);

    InOrder inOrder = inOrder(migrationServiceSpy, mongoMigrationRunner);

    inOrder.verify(migrationServiceSpy).updateCheckpointDate(any(Migration.class), any(Instant.class));
    inOrder.verify(mongoMigrationRunner).runMigrationForInterval(any(Migration.class), anyString(), any(Instant[].class));
```

What can I do? What's hapenning?

Comment: if you don't mock on spy object it will call the real method of the object. So you can check the real method before mocking it.

Comment: I also tried not to mock any method on the spy object, but in that case the spy is not aware about the  method was called. And I can-t use the original object instead the spy, since InOrder only acepts mocks or spies...

Comment: Also tried what you said (calling de funcionality to test and then create the spy, it does not work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to make the call on the spy object instead the real object:

```
migrationServiceSpy.updateStatus(DEFAULT_MIGRATION_ID, inProgressStatus);
```

instead of:

```
migrationServiceImpl.updateStatus(DEFAULT_MIGRATION_ID, inProgressStatus);
```